# Какой корень в слове СОЧУВСТВОВАТЬ?

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

Мне встречалось два основных варианта:

> со/чувств-
>
> сочувств-

Т.е. вопрос в том, выделять или не выделять приставку. Вопрос нетривиальный, поэтому просьба аргументировать свой ответ, желательно ссылаясь на авторитетные источники.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

- **Со-чу-в-ств-ов-а-ть** ("Словарь морфем русского языка" А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой);
- **со-чувств-ов-а-ть** ("Школьный словарь строения слов русского языка" З. А. Потихи);
- **сочувств-ова-ть** ("Комплексный словарь русского языка" А. Н. Тихонова);
- **со-чувств-ов-а-ть** ("Большой универсальный словарь русского языка" В. В. Морковкина).

Из МАС:

> СО…, *приставка* Употребляется при образовании глаголов и обозначает совместность, соучастие, сопутствие, например: *собеседовать, сонаследовать, сопричислить, сопровождать*.

Из этимологии слова (из словаря А. К. Шапошникова):

> Собств. рус. приставочное производное от глаг. *чувствовать*, калька
>   франц. *sympathiser* (avec qn), восходящего через искусственно-лат.
>   посредство к оригинальному греч. *σνμπαθέω* "сочувствовать,
>   сострадать".

Выводы:

1. Из приведенных разборов слова по составу можно видеть, что большинство словарей выделяют приставку в слове; тем не менее словари А. Н. Тихонова (включая словообразовательный) указывают на то, что *произошло переразложение*, и приставка *со* не выделяется вследствие утраты связи с ее значением "совместность, взаимность, соучастность".
2. Исходя из приведенных этимологических сведений становится ясно, что слово является [словообразовательной калькой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), то есть его морфемный состав соответствует морфемному составу французского слова, где выделяется приставка *sym-* (русская *со-*).
3. Так, возможны варианты разбора с выделением и невыделением приставки *со-*.

Comment: Какой корень в слове сочувствовать?

Comment: @shampar Как я уже писал, возможны три варианта разбора, где корни: 1) *-чу-*; 2) *-чувств-*; 3) *сочувств-*.

Answer (score 2):

**Чувств/о – со/чувств/ова/ть**, префиксально-суффиксальный способ образования слова, корень ЧУВСТВ.

**СОЧУВСТВОВАТЬ,** нсв. кому-чему. 1. Относиться с участием, состраданием к горю, переживаниям кого-л. 2. Относиться благожелательно к кому-, чему-л.; одобрять.

В то же время приставка СО может использоваться  при образовании глаголов префиксальным способом: **переживать – сопереживать, участвовать – соучаствовать** (из словаря Ефремовой).

Однако в приведенном примере глагол "сочувствовать" **не обозначает совместность действия** по отношению к глаголу "чувствовать", поэтому  глагол "сочувствовать" мотивируется существительным "чувство".

Comment: в приведенном примере?

Comment: В приведенном примере. Разобрано по составу: со/чувств/ова/ть, выделен корень ЧУВСТВ

Comment: В каком примере «глагол "сочувствовать" не обозначает совместность действия по отношению к глаголу "чувствовать"»?

Comment: Вообще не обозначает, значение глагола  "сочувствовать"   - это  относится с участием, а не "чувствовать совместно", как в глаголе "сопереживать".

Comment: Так не «в приведенном примере», а — в вашем случае. Вы же говорите о «примере», которого нет ни в ответе, ни в вопросе.

Comment: сочуствие не относится к участию, это именно относится к вопросу соместного переживания (трагедии например) с кем то кто ее уже "чувствует". что за бред. про участие